# Flutter - creating a search delegate data 'getter' model, from CSV data

Tags: json, flutter, csv, dart, search

At the moment, I am building a Flutter app to try and develop my skills, which includes a search delegate function. At the moment, my search delegate works great, when the data is imported from json format, which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: John,
    age: 22,
    height: 1.85,
    searchTerm: John 22 1.85,
  },
  {
    name: Alice,
    age: 24,
    height: 1.90,
    searchTerm: Alice 24 1.90,
  },
  {
    name: Bruce,
    age: 35,
    height: 1.76,
    searchTerm: Bruce 35 1.76,
  }
]
```

To allow my search delegate to work, I built a getter model that looks like this.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class People {
  final String name;
  final double age;
  final double height;
  final String searchTerm;

  People({
    required this.name,
    required this.age,
    required this.height,
    required this.searchTerm,
  });

  static People fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => People(
        name: json['name'],
        age: json['age'],
        height: json['height'],
        searchTerm: json['searchTerm'],
       
      );
}

class PeopleGetter {
  static Future<List<People>> getPeopleSuggestions(String query) async {
    try {
      final String response =
          await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/people.json');
      final List people = json.decode(response);

      return people
          .map((json) => People.fromJson(json))
          .where((people) {
        final searchTermLower = people.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
        final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
        return searchTermLower.contains(queryLower);
      }).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    throw '';
  }
}
```

This actually does work perfectly with my search delegate. However, since storing the data in a CSV file can significantly reduce the overall data size, and therefore the overall app size, I want to replace the json data with CSV data. I've tried modifying my 'getter' function from json data, to use CSV data (using the CSV package, from pub.dev), which you can see here:

```
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class People {
  final String name;
  final double age;
  final double height;
  final String searchTerm;

  People({
    required this.name,
    required this.age,
    required this.height,
    required this.searchTerm,
  });

  static People fromCSV(Map<String, dynamic> csv) => People(
        name: csv['name'],
        age: csv['age'],
        height: csv['height'],
        searchTerm: csv['searchTerm'],
       
      );
}

class PeopleGetter {
  static Future<List<People>> getPeopleSuggestions(String query) async {
    try {
      final String response =
          await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/people.csv');
      final List people = CsvToListConverter(response);

      return people
          .map((csv) => People.fromCSV(csv))
          .where((people) {
        final searchTermLower = people.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
        final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
        return searchTermLower.contains(queryLower);
      }).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    throw '';
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I use this version within the search delegate, I get the error:

`'type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`.

I feel like I'll just have made a very simple error somewhere but at the moment, I just can't spot it. I would really appreciate any help correcting my code, to allow me to search with CSV data, instead of JSON data. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to come from your `CsvToListConverter(response) ` could you post the code of that please ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That's actually a function provided by the package: https://pub.dev/packages/csv . According to their documentation, that particular function creates a list in the format List<List<dynamic>>. Could this be where the issue is coming from? It's possible that the json decoder creates a Map<String, dynamic>. How would I correct this issue?

Comment: Sorry, in fact it would make more sense that it comes from here `People.fromCSV(csv)`. As your csv is indeed a List<dynamic> and it expects a Map

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your data types are not corresponding anymore:

You provide a `List<dynamic>` to a function that expects a `Map<>`

`people.map((csv) => People.fromCSV(csv))`

```
  static People fromCSV(Map<String, dynamic> csv) => People(
        name: csv['name'],
        age: csv['age'],
        height: csv['height'],
        searchTerm: csv['searchTerm'],
      );
```

---

Could you try rewriting your function from CSV to adapt to the new incoming data ? I'm not sure what is the data you get but maybe something like that ?

```
static People fromCSV(List<dynamic> csv) => People(
        name: csv[0] ?? "",
        age: csv[1] ?? -1,
        height: csv[2] ?? -1,
        searchTerm: csv[3] ?? "",
      );
```

EDIT (fixing the few remaining bugs)

- Updated CSV package version
- Correctly retrieve the double from the csv
- Set the delimiter parameter to separate two people in the CSV

```
class People {
  final String name;
  final double age;
  final double height;
  final String searchTerm;

  People({
    required this.name,
    required this.age,
    required this.height,
    required this.searchTerm,
  });

  static People fromCSV(List<dynamic> csv) => People(
        name: csv[0] ?? '',
        age: double.parse(csv[1].toString()),
        height: double.parse(csv[2].toString()),
        searchTerm: csv[3] ?? '',
      );
}

class PeopleGetter {
  static Future<List<People>> getPeopleSuggestions(String query) async {
    try {
      final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.csv');
      final List<List<dynamic>> people =
          CsvToListConverter().convert(response, eol: "\n");
      return people.map((csv) => People.fromCSV(csv)).where((people) {
        final searchTermLower = people.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
        final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
        return searchTermLower.contains(queryLower);
      }).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    throw '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, your suggestion has solved the issue of 'type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' . However, there's a different error now, which is 'type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'double''. When I print the 'people' list that CsvToListConterter() outputs, it prints a list of all the column titles.

Comment: It seems that the error is coming from the return statement, where it says people.map(.... . What could be causing this?

Comment: Actually, looking at it, the print output of 'people' prints something in the format of [[] [] []]. I think because there's a lot of data, the statement has output an ellipsis at the end. I imagine that's exactly what the CsvToListConverter() function was intended to do. I'm just not sure where this error is coming from, as I haven't changed any of the input data, from the JSON to the CSV version.

Comment: I think I've worked out what is happening, compared to previously. Basically, 'people' is absolutely now in the format of [[] [] [] ...]. What we've got is that the first [] is the titles [name, age, height, searchTerm] and each subsequent one is the content for each person, which is obviously a combination of doubles and strings. I'll see if I can work out how to change my search query function to match and I'll post it as an answer. If you have any suggestions, I'll always appreciate them.

Comment: I edited to remove the first column as it allow to have only `People` in the data set. Dont forget to upvote / accept answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, it still isn't working. At the moment, the error is 'type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double''. It seems that whenever a search is made, it doesn't return anything. It seems as though the issue is once I return people.map((csv)... It's completely empty. Could it be something to do with people now being of the format [[], [], []] compared to [{}, {}, {}]?

Comment: Could you provide how is the data when when you get it from the csv file ? ```[["John", 18, 128, "..."], ["Nina", 25, 108, "..."], ...]``` right ?

Comment: Sure, so after CsvToListConverter(), but before converting it to a map, it looks like this: `[[John, 22, 1.85, John 22 1.85], [John, 22, 1.85, John 22 1.85], [John, 22, 1.85, John 22 1.85]]` So, it is as you have put, with the exception that the strings do not actually have quotation marks...

Comment: Try to remove the where clause, just to focus on the current issue ? And tell me if the data is still empty, if not are all the People object correctly filled ?

Comment: Wouldn't that remove the search functionality though? The 'where' was added so that the only entries returned are those 'where' they match the current search query. I've checked the data though and all objects do seem to be filled correctly.

Comment: It will, and thats the point, lets try to make it work without the filter, if it works then the problems is only in your where clause, the point of debugging is to narrow the problem in order to find the issue.

Comment: Good point. I'll give it a go and I'll let you know.

Comment: I've just had the opportunity to try it and unfortunately, it still isn't showing anything, which seems to suggest that the issue is to do with converting this new list (output as a result of the CsvToListConverter() function into a map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235349/discussion-between-wapazz-and-james).

Comment: Hey @James just notifying you I provided an answer since Im not sure you get notifs from our chat room. Cheers